# Take a string, capitalize only words with more than three characters unless it is in the beginning

Tags: ruby, string

When I enter as an input, "war and peace", I want, "War and Peace". The idea is to take a string and make it appear as it would as a headline or movie title. Capitalize all words in the string, unless the word is equal to or less than 3 and not in the beginning.

When I run this code:

```
def titleize(string)
      string.split(" ").take(1).join.capitalize
      string.split(" ").map do |x|

        x.capitalize! if x.length > 3

      end.join(" ")
end
```

It returns only " Peace".

Comment: The exception to a word that is <= 3 is if it is in the beginning; i.e., the capitalization ought to include 3-letter words if it starts the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
title = 'war and peace'

def titleize(input)
  input.split(' ').map.with_index { |word, index|
    index == 0 || word.length > 3 ? word.capitalize : word
  }.join(' ')
end


titleize title
=> "War and Peace"
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're only returning 'Peace' is because [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map)

> Invokes the given block once for each element of self.
>
> Creates a new array containing the values returned by the block.

When you do `x.capitalize! if x.length > 3`, you return `nil` if the `length <= 3`

```
"war" if "war".length > 3
# => nil
```

So to make this work, you'll need to make sure you're returning something for each word passed to the block

```
def titleize(string)
  string.capitalize.split.map do |x|
    x.length > 3 ? x.capitalize : x
  end.join(" ")
end

puts titleize("war and peace") # => "War and Peace"
```

Also, note that [`capitalize!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize-21)

> Modifies str by converting the first character to uppercase and the remainder to lowercase. Returns nil if no changes are made.

Whereas [`capitalize`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize)

> Returns a copy of str with the first character converted to uppercase and the remainder to lowercase.

so `x.capitalize!` could also return `nil`

```
"Peace".capitalize!
=> nil
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to convert the string into an array of words, capitalize words having more than three characters, joining them back into a string and capitalize the first character of the resulting string. Moreover, that would strip extra spaces, which may not be desired.

Instead, one can simply use [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a regular expression to make the substitutions.

```
r = /
    \A               # match the start of the string
    \p{Lower}        # match a lowercase letter
    |                # or
    (?<=[ ])         # match a space in a positive lookbehind
    \p{Lower}        # match a lowercase letter
    (?=\p{Alpha}{3}) # match 3 letters in a positive lookahead 
    /x               # free-spacing regex definition mode

str = "now is the    time for something to happen."

str.gsub(r) { |c| c.upcase }
  #=> "Now is the    Time for Something to Happen."
```

The regex is conventionally written

```
/\A\p{Lower}|(?<= )\p{Lower}(?=\p{Alpha}{3})/
```

I used `\p{Lower}` rather than `\p{Alpha}` to avoid unnecessary capitalizations.

Note that in free-spacing mode the space in the positive lookbehind is enclosed in a character class (`(?<=[ ])`). That's because free-spacing mode strips all spaces that are not so-protected.

Answer (score 0):

I would split the string into an array of strings like so:

```
string.split(' ')
```

Then capitalize each the first letter if the length of a given string is greater than 3:

```
for i in string.length
    if string[i].length > 3 
      string[i].capitalize
```

Now just join the string:

```
  string.join(' ')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def titleize(string)
  string.split.map.with_index {|x,i| if (i == 0 || x.length > 3) then x.capitalize else x end }.join(' ')
end
```

Note, this does not modify the string passed in, but you can do the following

```
foo = 'war and peace'
foo = titleize foo
puts foo
War and Peace
```